# how can I get Camera Intrinsic parameters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera-calibration

We are going to develop a mobile app that is going to take photos. But the app is supposed to get camera's intrinsic parameters like focal length and principal points, This is the constraint. Is it possible to get those parameters in flutter somehow? if so how can I get camera intrinsic parameters in flutter. IOS and Android give these paramters but I had search web but nothing found for flutter. I am very new in flutter,  I am not sure if I couldnt find it or there is not.

There are Android and IOS apis that gives this information, Can I write a package that gets these information from those native apis, is it possible or are there limits in flutter?

Comment: I have found that, even if android/ios apis by itselves does not give the camera intrinsic values. native apis return the camera intrinsic parameters as null. So I have gave up to search the answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you're wrong.For IOS ,see [Apple's document here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata).

Comment: It does not answer the question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32307907)